# I can't figure out how to work with the object returned by Firebase get query

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm building a React Native app with Expo and integrating Firebase (real time database) which I know has some limitations (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/). I'm trying to get a snapshot of the data using `await get(query(...` and have successfully done so, but I can't figure out exactly what I'm working with. When I `console.log` it I get this:

```
Object {
  "key1": value1,
  "key2": value2,
}
```

I was trying to return an array of the keys using `Object.keys()` but it returns this:

```
Array [
  "_node",
  "ref",
  "_index",
]
```

This doesn't line up with the examples of `Object.keys()` I'm seeing on the internet which makes me think this isn't a JSON object like I thought it was. I've tried poking around a good bit with some other stuff but can't figure it out. The problem is, when I use `typeof` on the object, it simply returns 'object' which is a little too vague for me to take to the google machine.

The following is a representation of my code. Thanks for your help.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { get, getDatabase, query, ref } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    databaseURL: '<myURL>',
    projectId: '<myID>',
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default async function myFunction() {
    const db = getDatabase(app);
    const readReference = ref(db, '/<I am only reading a piece of the data>')
    const existingData = await get(query(readReference))
    const dataKeys = Object.keys(existingData)
    console.log(dataKeys)
    console.log(existingData)
    console.log(typeof existingData)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get back from Firebase is known as a `DataSnapshot`, and contains the JSON of the location you read, and some more metadata.

If you just want to get the JSON value of the snapshot, use `snapshot.val()` as shown in the Expo documentation for [Storing Data and Receiving Updates](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#storing-data-and-receiving-updates).

Something like:

```
const existingData = await get(query(readReference))
const dataKeys = Object.keys(existingData.val())
console.log(dataKeys)
console.log(existingData.val())
console.log(typeof existingData.val())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Frank. I just didn't understand the DataSnapshot layer. That fixed the issue and now that I know, I'll go learn more about that.